# Middleman I18n generating translated files under /en/en/filename

Tags: internationalization, middleman

A default install of Middleman 4.1.10 with i18n 0.7.0 on Ruby 2.3.1p112 generates nested duplicate locales folders with broken links for the non-default language.

E.g, if Swedish is the default language, the translated english files get generated under /en/en/, with duplicates under /en/sv/, and files with broken links in swedish under /en/. The site´s primary language´s files get created correctly under /sv/. Changing the default language to English renders the same error, but then under /sv/sv/, with correct files and links under /en/ instead.

I stumbled on this when evaluating Middleman by converting an existing bi-lingual site. The same path/filename/link pattern is also reproducible on a default installation of Middleman with minimal configuration, as shown here.

I really can´t figure out if I went wrong somewhere, or if this is a bug in Middleman´s I18n module. Found nothing even remotely reminding of this by googling, on Stackoverflow, or Middleman´s documentation or bug reports, which makes me suspect I´m missing something embarrasingly obvious.

This is my setup:

---

```
config.rb

page '/*.xml', layout: false
page '/*.json', layout: false
page '/*.txt', layout: false
set :relative_links, true 
activate :i18n, :mount_at_root => :sv
```

Yes, I think I've tested all the other possible documented combinations of :i18n without any result. Manually setting the order between languages by :langs => [:en, :sv] only renders the same erroneous directory structure under sv.

---

```
locales/en.yml

---
en:
  index: Home
  news: News
  paths:
    index: index
    news: news
```

---

```
locales/sv.yml

---
sv:
  index: Hem
  news: Nyheter
  paths:
    index: index
    news: nyheter
```

---

```
source/layouts/layout.erb

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title></title>

<!-- The only change from defaults: -->
    <%= link_to t(:index), t("paths.index") + ".html" %> 
    <%= link_to t(:news), t("paths.news") + ".html" %>
```

```
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag :site %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag :all %>
  </head>

  <body class="<%= page_classes %>">
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

```
source/localizable/en/index.html.erb

---
title: English index
---
English index
```

---

```
source/localizable/en/news.html.erb

---
title: English news
---
English news
```

---

```
source/localizable/sv/index.html.erb

---
title: Swedish index
---
Swedish index
```

---

```
source/localizable/sv/news.html.erb

---
title: Swedish news
---
Swedish news
```

---

Obviously I expected this:

```
├── en
│   ├── index.html
│   └── news.html
│
└── sv
    ├── index.html
    └── nyheter.html
```

But got this:

```
├── en
│   ├── en
│   │   ├── index.html  # Both files with correct english translations and
│   │   └── news.html   # links, but only linked in the /en/en/ directory
│   │
│   ├── index.html      # Both files with swedish translations
│   ├── nyheter.html    #  and functioning links in swedish
│   │
│   └── sv
│       ├── index.html  # Both files with swedish translations and 
│       └── news.html   # links within the /en/sv/ directory
│  
└── sv
    ├── index.html      # Both files with correct swedish 
    └── nyheter.html    # translations and links
```